# Преобразование массива методами map или splice

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть массив такого вида

```
arr=[ 
{questions, settings},
{questions, settings},
{questions, settings}
]
```

Каждый questions, settings это в свою очередь объект. 
Каким методом перебрать массив, чтобы вернуть новый массив, состоящий из объектов  settings 
вот такой 
   `arr=[{},{},{}]` 
Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const newArr = arr.map(i => i.settings);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!